# CONCAT value in ON condition of JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables.

**Table: Geonames**:

- Country (2 character ISO code, e.g. SE)
- AdminArea (Char code, e.g. 0330)

**Table AdminAreas**

- AdminCode, (Combination of Coutry and AdminArea, e.g. "SE.0330")

So the ID of the AdminAreas that I want to join the tables on is a combination of columns on the first table. To join it I will need to join the two values from the Geonames table. Something like.

```
SELECT 
geoname.geonameid, geoname.name, geoname.latitude, geoname.longitude, 
geoname.country, geoname.admin1, admin_one.admin_id, admin_one.geoname_id 
FROM geoname 
INNER JOIN admin_one ON admin_one.admin_id = CONCAT(geoname.country, '.', geoname.admin1)
WHERE country='SE' LIMIT 10
```

Unfortunately, this is not working. It does not seem like i can `CONCAT` or do `string_agg()` on a JOIN. How do I get this JOIN working?

Comment: Seems like poor table design... Store the data in the same way everywhere.

Comment: @jarlh I'm importing data from an existing source. It's not my table design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine.  Perhaps one issue is that you have spaces or some other character.  I would recommend investigating this using:

```
SELECT gn.geonameid, gn.name, gn.latitude, gn.longitude, 
       gn.country, gn.admin1, ao.admin_id, ao.geoname_id 
FROM geoname gn LEFT JOIN
     admin_one ao
     ON ao.admin_id = CONCAT(TRIM(gn.country), '.', TRIM(gn.admin1))
WHERE gn.country = 'SE'
LIMIT 10;
```

This will return even unmatched results (because of the `LEFT JOIN`).  That might help you investigate the issue.

Comment: Not very efficient .. Indexes will be ignored , better to redesign .

Comment: Seems like you are right, the TRIM() helped it. I'm just doing an import of a lot of geoname data that is in a bad structure, so I don't care of doing it "nicely", it's just suppose to run a single time. Thanks.